# Processing error after upgrade to Version 6.0

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

With the following function I am trying to load the model into the earlier initialized viewer.

```
viewer.loadModel("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM/manifest/urn%3Aadsk.viewing%3Afs.file%3AdXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM%2Foutput%2FRai_04.3ds.svf")
```

Unfortuneately I get the following error for the function:

```
viewer3D.js:74844 Error while processing SVF: {"url":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM/manifest/urn%253Aadsk.viewing%253Afs.file%253AdXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM%252Foutput%252FRai_04.3ds.svf?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3002","httpStatus":400,"httpStatusText":"Bad Request","data":{"url":"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM/manifest/urn%253Aadsk.viewing%253Afs.file%253AdXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6aW1wbGVuaWFfaW1kL1JhaV8wNC4zZHM%252Foutput%252FRai_04.3ds.svf?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3002"}}
```

This is the way I initialize my viewer:

```
function onInitialized() { //console.log("viewer inizialized");
var config = Autodesk.Viewing.createViewerConfig();
config.extensions.push('Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow');
config.startOnInitialize = true;
config.theme = 'light-theme';
viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('main-viewer');  
viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D,Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D ,config);
viewer = viewerApp.getViewer(config);
viewer.start();
```

If I use the version 4.1 of the viewer, the model can be loaded this way. Changing to 6.0 the above described error appears.

I would really appreaciate a hint to a solution of my problem!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

With v6 and onwards, call wrapper method Viewer3D.load insteadof .loadModel so that the resource requests made to Forge endpoints can be formed properly:

```
viewer.load('https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/derivatives/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c2IyMzMvd2Fycmlvci4zZHM/output/warrior.3ds.svf');
```

or simply:

```
viewer.start(svfUrl)
```

Code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/9qncbuLt